# When using Angular CLI's "ng e2e", is it possible to have Protractor use Jasmine 3.5? OR fail fast with ng e2e

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm wanting to use some of the features within Jasmine 3.5 like `oneFailurePerSpec`.

If there's a way to do that with Jasmine 2.8, please point me there because it looks like Protractor 5.4.2 uses Jasmine 2.8.

Right now, I'm using a custom reporter to "fail fast" when a spec fails in the e2e suite, but I want to continue running other spec files, not just stop the whole process when 1 `it` statement fails.

Any guidance would be welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change the jasmine version in `package-lock.json` to the one you need and run `npm i`. In worse case scenario if protractor is incompatible with new jasmine, just roll back the changes

the jasmine version can be found at `package-lock.json/dependencies/protractor/requires/jasmine`